# C++ Printing out a list of pairs (created by overloaded operator)

Tags: c++, list

Just wondering how I can print out a list of pairs created by an overloaded assignment operator.

What I've already tried, as seen here, is create a an array (thus list1[5]) and assigning values to it. However, this doesn't seem like the best way to print out an entire set of say, 5 pairs of numbers since I'd have to print every single element separately using a loop.

This project actually originally had linked list functions which I've omitted because I'm not sure whether or not it's relevant but I suspect it may be necessary for printing out a list? I'd greatly appreciate any insight on what can be done other than printing out every element manually.

Pair.h:

```
#ifndef PAIR_H
#define PAIR_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Pair
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Pair& p);

public:
    Pair( );    
    Pair(int firstValue, int secondValue);
    ~Pair( );

    void setFirst(int);
    void setSecond(int);

    int getFirst( ) const;
    int getSecond( ) const;

private:
    int first;
    int second;
};

#endif
```

Pair.cpp

```
#include "Pair.h"

    //friend function
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Pair& p)
{
    out << "(" << p.first << "," << p.second << ")";
    return out;
}

Pair::Pair( )
{ 
    first = 0;
    second = 0;
}

Pair::Pair(int firstValue, int secondValue)
{
    first = firstValue;
    second = secondValue;
}

Pair::~Pair( ){ }

void Pair::setFirst(int newValue)
{
    first = newValue;
}

int Pair::getFirst( ) const
{
    return first;
}

void Pair::setSecond(int newValue)
{
    second = newValue;
}

int Pair::getSecond( ) const
{
    return second;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Pair.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testPair();

int main()
{
    testPair();
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void testPair()
{
    // Create your own testing cases after adding the class Pair.

    Pair list1[5], list2, list3;

    list1[1].setFirst(10);
    list1[1].setSecond(11);


    cout << "TEST: Pair <<\n\n";
    cout << "\tList1 is: " << list1[1] << endl;

    // NOTE: Do NOT make your class Pair a template.
}
```

Here it would only print (10, 11) but if I were to add more pairs to the list I'd have to print all of those out manually if I stick to this method.

Answer (score 0):

In case you know how many elements are within this list, you can just use a `for` loop to print all elements:

```
void print(Pair* pairs, unsigned int size)
{
    cout << "\tList is:" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "(*pairs)[i] << endl;
    }
}
```